internal remote config fetch error with flutter
If only the world could be so straightforward.
I am getting the following error when I try to configure firebase remote config:
initRemoteConfig failed with error: [firebase_remote_config/internal] internal remote config fetch error
I/flutter ( 5503): ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS----------------
I/flutter ( 5503): [firebase_remote_config/internal] internal remote config fetch error
I/flutter ( 5503): _initRemoteConfig failed with error: [firebase_remote_config/internal] internal remote config fetch error

The exception does not tell much, I know.
This is my code. Pretty simple:
Future<void> _initRemoteConfig() async {
  try {
    final cities = await loadDefaultConfig();
    final remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
    await remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
        fetchTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
        minimumFetchInterval: const Duration(hours: 1),
   ));
   await remoteConfig.setDefaults(<String, dynamic>{CitiesRemoteDataSource.citiesKey: 
   cities});
   await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrintStack();
    debugPrint("_initRemoteConfig failed with error: $e");
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
      e,
      null,
      information: ['_initRemoteConfig failed with error: $e'],
    );
  }
}

My api keys are properly set and the Firebase Remote Config API is also enabled in the google console.
